# How to embed JavaScript/CSS in HTML page using Rails' asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm developing a webpage, which content is fully generated with client-side JavaScript.  The only purpose of index.html is to refer to JavaScript and CSS documents, which are generated with Rails' asset pipeline.  To avoid extra requests, I'd like to inline those JavaScript and CSS in production.

How to inline JavaScript and CSS content which is generated with asset pipeline?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `Rails.application.assets` to get the content of the assets after precompilation. Add this in your `index.html.erb`:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  <%= raw Rails.application.assets['application.css'].to_s %>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  <%= raw Rails.application.assets['application.js'].to_s %>
</script>
```

Don't forget the `raw`, otherwise `"` will be changed into `&quot;` etc.

Note this isn't compressed; for production, you will probably want to inline compressed code. To do so, add `gem 'uglifier'` to your Gemfile, run bundle, and use this:

```
<%= raw Uglifier.new(:copyright => false).compile Rails.application.assets['application.js'].to_s %>
```

Comment: Thanks, works! And, in order to uglify JavaScript, `Uglifier.compile Rails.application.assets['application.js'].to_s`.

Comment: And if you want to uglify _without_ comments: `<%= raw Uglifier.new(:copyright => false).compile Rails.application.assets['application.js'].to_s %>`

Comment: Good tips for uglifying it. I added that to the answer.

Comment: I also had to set `config.assets.compile = true` in `production.rb` to be able to use `Rails.application.assets` in production :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use: `Rails.application.assets.find_asset('api.css').to_s`

Answer (score 0):

You probably **don't** want to inline those assets for performance in production. You would likely be much better off by serving them from a CDN like CloudFront and caching them along the way.

This should provide a better performance boost than cutting out 2 HTTP requests that are only rarely made.

Comment: This page contains no dynamic content (in fact contains no body content at all).  It just contains reference to scripts and stylesheets, so I intended to cache whole response and return it without any rendering.  I believe this would make better improvement than CDN which still requires additional requests.  Page content is built with JavaScript, data for that is grabbed via AJAX, I believe that saving this roundtrip and executing this AJAX call earlier is beneficial.

Comment: There's one good case for this (therefore I found this question/answer helpful): there are some third party services / libraries generating pdf's and some other types of documents from html/css.